# set key of $.load POST parameter from a variable

Tags: jquery, post, get

Can i set key(`searchParam`) from a variable?Like this using `$.load  POST` :

```
var searchParam = "code";
$("#myDiv").load("controller.html", {searchParam:searchString});
```

I kow there is another workaround using GET like :

```
$("#myDiv").load("controller.html?"+searchParam+"="+searchString});
```

but i prefer to use the first one,anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a plain object , set object `key` to `searchParam` using bracket notation, set object `value` to `searchString`

```
var searchParam = "code", data = {}; data[searchParam] = searchString;
$("#myDiv").load("controller.html", data);
```

Comment: What if I have `$("#myDiv").load("controller.html", {searchParam:searchString, anotherParam :"FULL"});` ?

Comment: @bumbumpaw _"What if I have $("#myDiv").load("controller.html", {searchParam:searchString, anotherParam :"FULL"}); ?"_ Should be able to repeat same process for additional keys , values set to `data` ; e.g., `data["anotherParam"] = "FULL";` before calling `$("#myDiv").load("controller.html", data);`